# Using GraphQl Mutation

Tags: graphql

I should use graphQl "query" and "mutation" through node.js request module.
I used "query" as:

`request("http://test.com/graphql/?query=query{allData{ Id, name, price  }}",
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);  });`

and it correctly returns all data for me.

I used the same code for "mutation" to create new data in database:

`request("http://test.com/graphql/?query=mutation{createData(name:'name-1',    price:1000)}}",  function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);

});`

But it didn't work correctly to put the new data in database.

Would you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mutation{createData(name:'name-1',price:1000){name price}}
```